# Struts 2 getText() error when resource key contains the same key

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have a error in Struts 2 (**version 2.3.16.3**) when obtain localized text from resource bundle with `getText()` Struts 2 tag.

In my resource.properties

```
label.text = Some Text
module2.label.text = Module 2
```

When I get text in JSP

```
<s:text name="label.text" />
<s:text name="module2.label.text" />
```

The result is always ***Some Text*** and never display ***Module2 Text***

I tried `<s:text name="label.text" searchValueStack="false"/> <s:text name="module2.label.text" searchValueStack="false"/>` but the result is the same

The package structure is

> webModule/src/resources/application.properties
>   webModule/src/resources/application_en_US.properties
>   webModule/src/resources/application_es_ES.properties
>   webModule/src/action/PageAction.java
>   webModule/web/jsp/Page.jsp

the struts.xml contains

```
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="resources.application"/>
```

Comment: show us the error message

Comment: I do not get any error message

Comment: Try with `searchValueStack="false"`.

Comment: I think the problem is that Struts 2 does a search in the stack with "contains" and as the second key contains the first ... always gets the value of the first key. Struts 1 does not happen that problem

Comment: You'll need to provide more info; this works for me without any problem if I use the default package-level resource file `package.properties` and do nothing in my action. How are you configuring everything, what's your resource file structure, etc.?

Comment: the file structure is: 
webModule/src/resources/application.properties, 
webModule/src/resources/application_en_US.properties, 
webModule/src/resources/application_es_ES.properties,
webModule/src/action/PageAction.java, 
webModule/web/jsp/Page.jsp,

Comment: And how did you configure S2 to use that property file? Note that this filename is not the same as in your question, which makes it even harder to determine what you're doing.

Comment: the struts.xml contains <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="path.to.resources.application"/>

Comment: I display correct any message in any language, but the problem is when the keys contains another key... "label.text" and "module2.label.text" for example

Comment: Aleksandr M, you can tell me how to assign searchValueStack

Comment: First of all use `@Name` to mention somebody (@J.PatricioGarcía). Second: don't post additional information in the comments edit your question instead. Third: what exactly do you mean by `path.to.resources.application`? You can try with `<s:text name="label.text" searchValueStack="false"/>` see if it makes any difference. Also which version of S2 are you using?

Comment: Do you have package `module2`?

Comment: I do not have that package

Comment: Do you have `module2.label.text` property with `Module 2` value in all properties files?

Comment: yes, I have that key in all properties files

Comment: Well like Dave said this should work without any problems. Could you create a minimal example project with this problem and upload it somewhere (github, bitbucket, ...).

Comment: ok, for now I rename the keys... Just have time I upload example proyect...

Comment: I tried with the same keys with struts 2.3.15.3 jar and I get the expected result i.e. displaying the both keys on jsp page. It is displaying both key values on jsp.